# Is it possible to check file content type (mime) using Excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel

Precisely, Is it possible to check if a file is actually a mp3 file (not by extension, but by content) using Excel VBA?

Edit: Adding codes for two attempts that I made:

Attempt 1 - Based on inputs from microsoft community. Strangely, this validates all files as mp3, don't know what I am missing.

```
Sub mp3_test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim c As clsMP3Info ' name of the class module
Dim nSecs As Long

book1 = ThisWorkbook.Name

MsgBox "Please select the folder that contains files to be checked.", vbExclamation

'FILE_EXT = "xlsx"
strFolderName = Get_Folder_Path() & "\"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSO_FOLDER = FSO.GetFolder(strFolderName)

i = 2
If FSO_FOLDER.Files.Count > 0 Then

For Each FSO_FILE In FSO_FOLDER.Files
'pq = q
sFile = strFolderName & FSO_FILE.Name

      Set c = New clsMP3Info
      With c
             If Len(sFile) Then c.Filename = sFile
             If Not c.ValidMP3 Then
                     Range("B" & i).Value = "Invalid"
                     Range("A" & i).Value = FSO_FILE.Name
                     i = i + 1
             Else
                     Range("B" & i).Value = "Valid"
                     Range("A" & i).Value = FSO_FILE.Name
                     i = i + 1
                     End If
       End With
Next
End If

s = MsgBox("Done!", vbOKOnly)    
End Sub
```

Attempt 2 - Based on the code same shared by @Steven in this post/thread. This gives overflow error as the variable doesn't seem to accept size over 32767 bytes.

```
Sub mp3c()

Dim intFileNum As Integer, bytTemp As Byte
Dim bytes() As Byte
intFileNum = FreeFile

Open "D:\Users\adminx\Desktop\Test\Audioslave - Revelations - 07 - Somedays.mp3" For Binary Access Read As intFileNum

Dim i As Long

i = 0

Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)
    Get intFileNum, , bytTemp
    ReDim Preserve bytes(i + 1)
    bytes(i) = bytTemp
    i = i + 1
Loop

Close intFileNum

Dim headerSize, width, height As Long

width = BytesToInt(bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 0), bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 1), bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 2), bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 3))
height = BytesToInt(bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 0), bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 1), bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 2), bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 3))
headerSize = BytesToInt(bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 0), bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 1), bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 2), bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 3))
End Sub
```

Comment: I think yes. If you are talking about files with `.mp3` extensions but actually named `something.mp3.exe` with the file extension hidden, then yes, you can use VBA to check if it really is an mp3 file or nor. But still your question lack context and may be off topic here.

Comment: thanks! let me know how i can add more context. and/or what other topic i can add. i am working on the answer though based on the responses here and will add full answer once i have it.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you could open the file for binary access and read the file header. Below is a snippet from a project where I read a bitmap's header, obviously you would need to change the offset's to get the required information from the MP3 file.

```
Dim intFileNum As Integer, bytTemp As Byte
Dim bytes() As Byte
intFileNum = FreeFile

Open filePath For Binary Access Read As intFileNum

Dim i As Integer

i = 0

Do While Not EOF(intFileNum)
    Get intFileNum, , bytTemp

    ReDim Preserve bytes(i + 1)

    bytes(i) = bytTemp

    i = i + 1
Loop

Close intFileNum

Dim headerSize, width, height As Long

width = BytesToInt(bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 0), bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 1), bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 2), bytes(WIDTH_OFFSET + 3))
height = BytesToInt(bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 0), bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 1), bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 2), bytes(HEIGHT_OFFSET + 3))
headerSize = BytesToInt(bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 0), bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 1), bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 2), bytes(HEADERSIZE_OFFSET + 3))
```

Edit: Probably should have included my BytesToInt function which converts a dword into an integer:

```
Function BytesToInt(a As Byte, b As Byte, c As Byte, d As Byte) As Double

    BytesToInt = (d * 256 ^ 3) + (c * 256 ^ 2) + (b * 256) + a

End Function
```

Comment: thanks! i am working on modifying the code to check for mp3, will add the answers once i have it

Comment: hi @steven i have been trying several ways since the last 3 days but unfortunately haven't had any luck yet. could you please guide with some more inputs.

Comment: You need to do a bit more work than just copy and paste what I sent you. I was reading some information from a bitmap header, you need to figure out how and MP3 header is put together to verify that the file is an MP3. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8295/MPEG-Audio-Frame-Header

Comment: i understand. how do i make sure that i am reading the right part/amount of data from the file? then i can use this info to do more -  http://www.datavoyage.com/mpgscript/mpeghdr.htm or basically from the link you shared.

Comment: Using this as an example: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Mp3filestructure.svg

If I wanted to read the version I would simply read the 4th byte. In your code you would do this by using bytes(4).

Comment: hi @steven thanks for all your inputs so far! i have been constantly trying but unfortunately haven't gotten to anything. I used your method to read the file bit by bit and i essentially get a string if i encode it to characters. the best logic i have as of now is to search for words like "ID3" and "LAME" in that string. I am not able to utilize the mp3 header structure to validate the file. can you help a bit more?